# Unable to select imported certificate into AWS load balancer listener

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

For some reason, the drop-down select for the certificate is not showing when I go to add it to the HTTPS listener for my EC2 instance.
In the ACM, it is "Issued", so I don't see why it shouldn't show up.

**HTTPS Listener**

[image: certificate missing in HTTPS load balancer EC2 listener]

**Here's the ACM console, shows my certificate is issued**

[image: ACM manager]

Comment: Are EB and ACL cert in the same region?

Comment: What does ACL stand for, the certificate is imported from Porkbun

Comment: I meant, ACM, sorry.

Comment: You must mean to check the ARN, right?  Let me see...

Comment: Everywhere i look, in EB configuration, ACM, EC2, it's all the same region, although i might not be looking in the right place.

Comment: That's good. What about type of cert? ALB does not support  all types, even though ACM does. For example, if you imported cert is 4096 in length, it can't be used on ALB.

Comment: When I expand the box it does show:  Public key info RSA 4096-bit

Comment: Yes. So that's the reason. 4096 is too long and will not work with load balancer. If you don't mind I will provide an answer with some extra info and links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The reason for not being able to use imported SSL cert into ACM on ALB, is because its **too long**. The import cert is `RSA 4096-bit`, however, ALB (and other AWS services) are compatible with `2048-bit RSA (RSA_2048)` or `1024-bit RSA (RSA_1024)` as explained in:

- [Why can't I find my imported certificate for my load balancer or CloudFront distribution?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-ssl-tls-certificate-https/)

> The certificate imported into ACM is using an algorithm **other that 1024-bit RSA or 2048-bit RSA**.

The [possible solution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-https-listener.html#https-listener-certificates) is to use IAM for these certificates:

> ACM supports RSA certificates with a 4096 key length and EC certificates. However, you cannot install these certificates on your load balancer through integration with ACM. You must **upload these certificates to IAM** in order to use them with your load balancer.

Comment: Amazingly, i got it working using the Amazon issued certificate, this is after a month of frustration... thanks for the help.  The reason I couldn't do it before is because I had changed my authoritative servers from porkbun's to aws.  I changed it back and now the certificate gets issued.  But now I can't access the site ((

Comment: @LawrenceDeSouza No problem. Maybe have to wait a bit for the cert to take effect? If not, you can consider making new issue with relevant info to it.